# Splitting and grouping records into daily sets using d3.js and dc.js

Tags: d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I am new to [d3.js](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki) and [dc.js](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki) and I have spend the best part of a week reading through the [tutorials](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Tutorials) and [API](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/API-Reference). It has a relatively steep learning curve however I am (slowly) becoming familiar with the individual manipulations. That said I still lack the practical experience to construct what I need.

I have a JSON file that contains the following data structure (The record set is relatively large ~2 million objects):

```
[
    {
        "index": "device_1",
        "state": -1,
        "frequencies": [
            "800PS"
        ],
        "events": [
            {
                "start": "04/07/2014 04:24:19",
                "end": "07/21/2014 08:53:19",
                "name": "event_1234"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "index": "device_2",
        "state": 1,
        "frequencies": [
            "2100AWS",
            "1900PCS"
        ],
        "events": [
            {
                "start": "02/20/2014 04:03:20",
                "end": "04/30/2014 07:24:35",
                "name": "event_3456"
            },
            {
                "start": "04/30/2014 07:25:37",
                "end": "07/01/2014 06:35:44",
                "name": "event_766"
            },
            {
                "start": "06/02/2014 00:02:16",
                "end": "06/02/2014 00:04:25",
                "name": "event_8967"
            },
            {
                "start": "06/11/2014 15:38:59",
                "end": "06/11/2014 15:41:15",
                "name": "event_385"
            },
            {
                "start": "06/28/2014 07:37:00",
                "end": "06/28/2014 07:39:34",
                "name": "event_8959"
            },
            {
                "start": "07/01/2014 07:06:06",
                "end": "07/03/2014 03:27:55",
                "name": "event_2654"
            },
            {
                "start": "07/03/2014 04:16:55",
                "end": "07/21/2014 08:53:19",
                "name": "event_94768"
            }
        ]
    },
...
]
```

What I am trying to achieve is to organise the data so I can create a **daily uptime** report per device where I gather a cumulative event time per day per device.

Effectively I am trying to convert the original data (above) into a new dataset that looks something like this:

```
    [
        {"device":"device_1", "date": "01/01/2014", "cumulative": 2530},
        {"device":"device_2", "date": "01/01/2014", "cumulative": 1234},
        {"device":"device_1", "date": "01/02/2014", "cumulative": 456},
        {"device":"device_2", "date": "01/02/2014", "cumulative": 198},
        ...
    ]
```

* *Where ***cumulative*** is the number of seconds that all cumulative events occurred on that day for that device.*

Once I get to that stage I can use something like: `d3.nest().key().rollup().entries()` to sort and group the data ready for display.

I suspect that d3 has a built in mechanism to handle this situation but my current approach is as follows:

- Import the data set

  ```
  d3.json("data.json", function(error, json_data) {
  if (error)return console.warn(error);
  ...
  }
  ```
- Convert the Strings to date objects

  ```
  var dateFormat = d3.time.format("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S");
  json_data.forEach(function(d) {

          d.dstart = d.events.map(function(x) {
              return dateFormat.parse(x.start);
          });

          d.dend = d.events.map(function(x) {
              return dateFormat.parse(x.end);
          });

      });
  ```
- Specify a ***start*** and ***end*** date range for the report at daily intervals
- Determine if an event spanned across more than 1 day, if so break the event into several segments
- Sum the cumulative duration of the daily device events

***(N.B. I do have control over the JSON data format! I could technically create the final dataset directly. However, the current format is very useful for other reports and I am keen to avoid having two data files as they are <20MB each so ideally I need to avoid changing the JSON design.)***

Comment: There may be other libraries that will help with this, but d3 is not really a data preprocessing library. I think you are on the right track. And you shouldn't need to change your format unless that file size is causing slowdowns.

Comment: Have you by chance come across a library that might be able to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

The data structure that comes to mind is an interval tree.  I haven't tried this library but it might help - [interval tree](https://github.com/shinout/interval-tree).

Otherwise, at least you could skip the last step and just break events by day.  Accumulation is what crossfilter is great at - use `reduceSum`.