# Crossfilter (d3js/dcjs) get group size in group

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

This is a follow on question from [Splitting and grouping records into daily sets using d3.js and dc.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24906877/splitting-and-grouping-records-into-daily-sets-using-d3-js-and-dc-js).

I have a data set structure that looks as follows:

```
[
    {"device":"device_1", "date": "01/01/2014", "cumulative": 2530},
    {"device":"device_2", "date": "01/01/2014", "cumulative": 1234},
    {"device":"device_1", "date": "01/02/2014", "cumulative": 456},
    {"device":"device_2", "date": "01/02/2014", "cumulative": 198},
    ...
]
```

I am trying to create a bar chart using [crossfilter](https://github.com/square/crossfilter) to display the **total uptime as a %** on the Y-Axis and the **date** on the X-Axis. The cumulative is a value in seconds and given that there are (roughly/generally) 86400 seconds in a day I can get the % uptime for a single device pretty easily:

```
d3.json("daily.json", function(error, json_data) {
...
    json_data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.dd = dateFormat.parse(d.date);
    ...
    });

    var das = crossfilter(json_data);
    var all = das.groupAll();

    // dimension by date
    var dateDimension = das.dimension(function(d) {
        return d.dd;
    });
    var uptimeDaysGroup = dateDimension.group().reduceSum(function(d) {
        return Math.round(((86400 - d.cumulative) / 86400) * 100);
    });
...
}
```

The problem being *(as you can see from the original dataset)* there is more than one device per day. The number of devices could be anywhere between 1 and 500K, so I need to modify the `uptimeDaysGroup` function to take this into account by somehow obtaining the number of objects that have been added to the group for a given day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to create a custom grouping and track the total cumulative for the group (or the total uptime %) as well as the number of devices and then divide by the number of devices. At the risk of being sort of self-promoting, [reductio](https://github.com/esjewett/reductio) is a library of Crossfilter grouping helper functions and you could use its average calculation functionality to do this without having to put together the custom grouping yourself:

```
reductio().count(true)
    .sum(function(d) { return Math.round(((86400 - d.cumulative) / 86400) * 100); })
    .avg(true)(uptimeDaysGroup);
```

This should result in a group structure with a key of the date and a "value" object with count, sum, and avg properties. There's also an exception aggregation option, but since you only have one unique record per device per day, you shouldn't need that.

Comment: Thanks, this is very useful. I just have one question that is not clear from the docs. Once I have the newly reduced group e.g.`{ key: 'date', value: { count: 3, sum: 10}}` (.avg(false)). In order to  get the % I need to do some maths with the `sum` and `count`. Once I have done that how do I then convert the group to: `{ key: 'date', value:21}` (where value is my calculated %)?

Comment: I'd suggest if you're using dc.js, just define your calculation in the valueAccessor for your chart. Like chart.valueAccessor(function(d) { return d.value.sum / d.value.count; }). I wouldn't change the groups.